# Oracle BPEL 12c The prefix "fn-bea" used in the qualified name "fn-bea:serialize" can not be resolved

Tags: xquery, oracle12c, bpel

I'm trying to use `fn-bea:serialize($iter)` to get xml node content as string in Oracle BPEL 12c XQuery functions but I'm recieving

> The prefix "fn-bea" used in the qualified name "fn-bea:serialize" can
>   not be resolved

In Oracle OSB 12c I don't have any problems using the same XQuery function, but I need to use it in Oracle BPEL.

I'll apreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `fn:serialize` which should be available in both OSB and BPEL 12.  OSB and BPEL use the same XQuery processor internally.  When you invoke XQuery from BPEL, just make sure you are using the 1.0 XQuery processor/function.